# image moves navbar list up (not centered)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to add my image inside my navbar-header so that it adjusts alongside the header links. however since the size of the image is larger it increases and leaves spaces on the other header links. how do i keep the links centered?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header logo">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-left"><img src="img/logo_png_solo.png"></a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="main" class="mwc-font-med">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="cards/membership.php" class="mwc-font-med">Membership</a></li>
          <li><a href="main" class="mwc-font-med">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="faq" class="mwc-font-med">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#" class="mwc-font-med">Register</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="mwc-font-med">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

NO IMAGE:

[image: 1]

WITH IMAGE:

[image: 2]

Comment: can give me whole navbar pen or fiddle ? because you can solve this problem with flexbox css

Answer (score 0):

Try using navbar-brand

```
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:#FFF">
         <img src="img/logo_png_solo.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
              Your name
       </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your logo doesn't have padding, but the texts in the navbar have. just give padding between 10-15 px to the div containing the image